# "read" not working if called inside bash while loop

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

Why the read function inside this while loop not working? if i uncomment echo (and comment read) it prints several times, but if the "read" is uncommented it just exits function. Same "read" works outside loop.

```
readTest()
{
  ls -l | while read -r files; do
    read -p "Continue? (Y/N): " confirm && [[ $confirm == [yY] || $confirm == [yY][eE][sS] ]] || exit 1
    #echo "tttt"
  done

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the `read` in the `while` line and the `read` in the loop body will read from the pipe, not from the terminal. The output from `ls` does not match the patterns, so the `exit` command will be called.

Parsing the output of `ls` is error-prone. You should better use something like

```
for files in *; do
    read -p "Continue? (Y/N): " confirm && [[ $confirm == [yY] || $confirm == [yY][eE][sS] ]] || exit 1
    #echo "tttt"
done
```

This would avoid the input redirection for the inner `read`.

If you don't need to exit from the whole shell script, I suggest `break` or `return` instead of `exit`.

---

**More detailed explanation** to answer a comment

In a simplified example

```
ls | while read -r files; do
    read confirm
done
```

and assuming `ls` prints

```
foo
bar
baz
```

in the first iteration, `read -r files` will get `foo`, then `read confirm` will get `bar`,
in the second iteration, `read -r files` will get `baz`, then `read confirm` will get EOF,
in the third iteration, `read -r files` will get EOF and terminate the loop.

Comment: wont the pipe exit when the ls finishes? @Bodo ?

Comment: @Nasir see More detailed explanation